# How to keep 2 JPanels aligned vertically to each other?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Ok, I am pretty new to Java swings and is trying to learn the tricks of it but is struggling with the alignment of 2 JPanels in the frame. If you look at the below screenshot, my column name JPanel alignment and its below JPanel alignment is not aligning to each other properly.

Below is my code.

```
    JPanel columns = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.weighty = 1.0;
    gbc.weightx = 1.0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;


    text = "<html><b>Action</b></html>";        
    JLabel label_action = new JLabel(text);
    columns.add(label_action, gbc);
    columns.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());


    JPanel values= new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    values.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());  

    gbc.weighty = 1.0;
    gbc.weightx = 1.0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;

  DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();

    model.addElement("click");
    model.addElement("Input Keys");

    final JComboBox<String> comboBox1 = new JComboBox<String>(model);
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(comboBox1);
    comboBox1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 22));
    values.add(comboBox1, gbc);
    values.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

[image]

Comment: Remove all calls to `setLayout`.  You already created each JPanel with a layout (specifically, a GridBagLayout).  Setting a new layout will discard all of your previously specified constraints.

Comment: Removing setLayout from both JPanel gives a compilation error. Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal anchor value

Comment: You need to be using a single JPanel, with your titles in row zero of the grid.

Comment: That image makes it look like that data should be presented in a `JTable` ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't even bother to work with `GridBagLayout`. It is a poorly designed layout manager that does not meet today's requirements. I recommend either 
`MigLayout` or `GroupLayout`.

Look how easy is to create your layout with `MigLayout`:

```
package com.zetcode;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigLayoutAlignmentEx extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutAlignmentEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout());

        JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("Action");
        JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("Choose Selector");
        JLabel lbl3 = new JLabel("Element Properties");
        JLabel lbl4 = new JLabel("Values");
        JLabel lbl5 = new JLabel("Element Name");
        JLabel lbl6 = new JLabel("Comments");

        JComboBox combo1 = new JComboBox();
        JComboBox combo2 = new JComboBox();

        JTextField field1 = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField field2 = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField field3 = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField field4 = new JTextField(15);

        add(lbl1);
        add(lbl2);
        add(lbl3);
        add(lbl4);
        add(lbl5);
        add(lbl6, "wrap");

        add(combo1, "w 150lp");
        add(combo2, "w 150lp");
        add(field1);
        add(field2);
        add(field3);
        add(field4, "wrap");

        pack();

        setTitle("MigLayout example");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            MigLayoutAlignmentEx ex = new MigLayoutAlignmentEx();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });        
    }
}
```

Your UI is super easy to create; you just put the components into the cells. However, unlike in `MigLayout`, where the grid is precreated, in
`GridBagLayout` you have to create each cell manually, which is difficult and error prone.

[image]

Comment: Wow! You seem *obsessed* with `MigLayout`. Did you program that layout manager?

Comment: `MigLayout` was created by Mikael Grev. It is easy to use and very flexible. One of the few managers that can fulfill the requirements of modern UI.